# Dynamic selection of dataframe fields by value comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I can get the sum of all values in a dataframe meeting specified conditions by typing

```
df.loc[(df[column_1] == value_1) & (df[column_2] == value_2), columnWithValues].sum()
```

I am looking for an easy solution which uses a set with columns and values specified.
Is there something like the following?

```
set_columns = set([column_1, column_2])
set_values = set([value_1, value_2])
df.loc[set_col == set_val, columnWithValues].sum()
```

This way, the input could have any number of arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the columns' names to query on in a **list**, and the target values in a **tuple**; Set the columns as index on the data frame and then query with values:

```
columns = ['column_1', 'column_2']
values = ('value_1', 'value_2')

df.set_index(columns).loc[values, columnWithValues].sum()
```

*Example*:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        "A": [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
        "B": [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
        "C": [2,1,2,3,4,3,5,6],
        "D": [5,3,2,1,6,7,8,9]
    })

columns = ['A', 'B']
values = (2,4)
df.set_index(columns).loc[values, ['C','D']].sum()

#C    11
#D    17
#dtype: int64
```

Comment: Wow, this is genius. Thanks a lot!